# How to constrain the number of following backslashes to an odd number? to an even number?

Tags: alloy

`next` is a binary relation.

This string:

```
A\\\,B
```

is modeled by this `next` table:

[image: The "next" table which models <code>A\\\,B</code>]

Consider the first column of the first row of the table. It's value is A. From A we can get to Backslash0, then Backslash1, then Backslash2, then Backslash3, then Comma0, and then B. So, the number of Backslashes between A and the first reachable non-backslash value (which in this case is Comma0) is an odd number (3). Yea! That is what I want. If the first reachable non-backslash value was a non-comma, then the number of intervening Backslashes must be even (0, 2, 4, ...).

**How do I express this constraint in Alloy:**

> For each non-backslash value c in the first column of the next table:
>   If the first non-backslash value c' reachable from c is a comma, then
>   the number of backslashes between c and c' must be odd (1, 3, 5, ...).
>   If the first non-backslash value c' reachable from c is a non-comma,
>   then the number of backslashes between c and c' must be even (0, 2, 4,
>   ...).

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if you're modeling this at the right level of abstraction. Is it necessary to consider the structure of the backslash sequence? What if you had two tokens, the double-backslash and backslash-comma, and just said required backslash-comma to be preceded by double-backslash and followed by non-backslash?

Comment: Hi @Daniel Jackson. I already tried the more abstract approach (see my SO post titled "Is this Alloy model cheating". I wanted to see if the less abstract approach could be modeled in Alloy.

Comment: I believe that  your questions (is it cheating ? am I doing the right thing? is it the right level of abstraction?) can't be properly addressed if you don't tell us explicitly the purpose of your model.